# Clearing an array which is global context

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
  obj.arr1 = [],
  obj.arr2 = []
};
```

I have this object in the global context, now each time when i add a new user the `obj1.arr[]` is used for some manipulation. Now when i add another user, the value obj.arr1[] holds the previous data.

I tried using `obj.arr1=[];` but this does not work. I feel my object is in global context, how can i clear it.

Comment: Are you sure? This isn't valid Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your object is wrong syntax, should be

```
var obj = {
  arr1: [],
  arr2: []
};
```

And what is `obj1` ? What do you want to clear?